# Push Notifications not coming when published on test flight

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, testflight

I have tested `push notifications` as a developer account and it worked, But when I tried to put it on TestFlight for the testers to test it, it didn't show a push notification but the data is correctly received. So is there a kind of `certificate` that I need to generate for `TestFlight` or there is some issues in my profiles?
Push notification works when I install the app through `XCode`, but when I install it from test flight it is not working.

Comment: Are you using the production APNS certificate for the apps distributed using TestFlight? Also, what is the APNS response when you send a notification to the app distributed using TestFlight?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that your are using development APNS certificate.
For TestFlight users you need to send push notifications with production APNS (because when your are creating archive of your project, it's generated with release build settings). You can generate it in apple's developer portal: in your application settings page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GhKaren is right. You have to use Production APNS when you upload app on itunesconnect and distribute it on Test-flight.